# DIY TP4056 Li-Ion does not charge

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, lithium-polymer, tp4056

I created a DIY TP4056 Li-Ion charger, but for some reason it does not charge. Here is the schematic I created in EasyEDA.  I tried replacing R4 with 2k - no effect.

The red LED keeps flashing when I connect the charger.

Has anyone got an idea? Maybe there is an error in my schematic?

[image: TP4056 charger with adjustable current limit]

Comment: Welcome! What Vcc do you measure when you connect a battery?

Comment: The solder connection is properly made, checked it twice. 

The battery has a voltage of 3.8 volts. 

I'm charging it from a 5V USB power supply with a USB type C cable. 

Is my schematic correct or did I forget something? 

The strange thing is, when I bridge B- and OUT-, it starts charging!?

Comment: Why is OUT+ connected to B+ but OUT- is not connected to B-?

Comment: @Barry: Because B- should get connected to GND through Q1.

Comment: Please measure Vcc with your 3.7 V battery connected. Preferably with oscilloscope. Please also measure the two gate voltages of Q1.

Comment: found the problem. Seems like a few of my boards were broken for some reason. 
The rest seem to work without any problems.